# Can a finite number of questions ever fall short to clarify "what you mean"?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

So here's something I was pondering about. Let's say there are 2 people A and B.
A says a sentence with a double entendre and B asks for a clarification. For example:

A: Miners Refuse to Work After Death

B: Do you mean the ghost of a miners refused to work after death or do you mean the miner refused to work after someone else's death?

A: Obviously, the latter!

Notice B was able to clarify A what A meant with one question.

Now, here's my question can one construct a finite sentence/stanza/book which can be only clarified only via an infinite number of questions?

I'm more interested in the axioms used in arriving at the answer than a simple yes/no

Comment: My guess would be to make up a statement where the clarification questions loop back on themselves.  Statement involves "A", "A" means "B,C,D", "C" means "A, X, Y".

Comment: @Dave I should have thought of that. Interestingly, I think this also shows language is never circular. For example a dictionary would be useless if I look up the definition of courageous it will say brave but then for brave is says courageous.

Comment: I am.not sure exactly what you are getting at here. If the first person gives more specific details then there are less questions one can ask. The issue is person A is not specific enough where there has to be additional questions. Be specific & detailed in the first place & you avoid the issue altogether! As far as some dictionaries  they are circular. For instance look up human being & often the dictionary will define that as a person. Look up person & that will often define that as a human being. That goes to show we really may not KNOW what a human being is! Can you show otherwise?

Comment: There are certainly mathematical examples. It takes infinitely many yes/no questions (or binary digits) to fully specify any noncomputable real number. Of course this is not a real-world situation so I'm not sure if you'd find it of interest.

Comment: "Clarification" is inherently vague, and depends on presumed cognitive habits and shared background as much as on the meanings themselves, if not more. You'd be surprised how simple a thing can be that cannot be clarified with *any* number of questions. See [Carroll's What the Tortoise Said to Achilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_the_Tortoise_Said_to_Achilles) for an infinite sequence of questions that still fails to "clarify" a *modus ponens*.

Comment: @user4894 what about pointing to a stick that has a mark p units up its length where p = said number?

Comment: @JKusin Well the problem is that sticks are made of atoms and are subject to the laws of physics. You can't measure any more precisely than the Planck length. You only need finitely many bits. If there are quantities in the physical world that require infinitely many bits to represent, they lie beyond the scope of known physics.

Comment: @user4894 I agree we can't physically measure infinitely precise in practice or in theory (i.e GR in this case), but a continuum (of space, frequencies, etc) isn't ruled out, and GR is known to be incomplete or conflict with other theories. I'm playing extreme devil's advocate here.

Comment: @JKusin I would never doubt what might be possible in future physics. If professor so-and-so in Helsinki discovers a physical instantiation of infinity, we'll all hear about it. Till then, we're in the realm of science fiction. I assume we're in agreement.

Comment: @user4894 Yes pretty close I'd say!

Comment: As Logikal says, continuous look up of words in dictionaries definitions end up being circular. Iirc, someone demonstrated it couldn't be otherwise, but I don't remember who. Furthermore in your example, it is not clear that A and B really agree on what A means. For example B could think he knows what A means by "miner", but be wrong. All of it presupposes they both share a common understanding of the words they use. Something that can't be done through language only. At some point A and B will need a common object as reference (for example, an actual miner)

Comment: Yes, for example if you believe in principle of sufficient reason (PSR) without brute facts, then an infinite inquiry chain of the efficient reason of every contingent being/fact still falls short to clarify the necessary being...

Comment: Do people always *know what they mean*? No. Internal clarification is rarely about 'asking yourself questions'. So I would say no, finite questions are not capable of determining all & every minutiae of meaning. Also, Godel Incompleteness implies true but unprovable points can continue to be made beyond what can be recursively enumerated from claims with any complex-ish system. So truths hidden to both parties, but there, may be involved

Answer (score 1):

The nature of the clarification relation is of importance here. Lets first consider the formalities. Here are a couple of different clarification relations:

1. You have an amphibilous language, ie a (well formed) formula f has multiple syntactical *meanings*. Then a clarification of f is a resolution of f as some of those *meanings*, for simplicity, a proper subset of those possible *meanings*.
2. You have two languages, L1 and L2, a clarification of a formula f1 in L1 is a reduction of f1 to some formula f2 in L2. There's also a semantic formulation here as well.
3. The clarification relation is a process via which someone *understands* some sentence that they did not *understand* prior.

Note that these relations are not necessarily mutually exclusive (and probably not exhaustive either). For example, it is clear that the sentence "all people love someone" is amphibilous *in the english language*, a clarification might consist both of a specification of a particular syntactic formulation as well as some level of understanding that follows.

More generally: A relation of type 3 will rely on the agents who engage in the discourse, it is completely possible that a PhD will never be able to clarify the meaning of the wave function to a 3 year old. The first and second are a bit more interesting. A type 2 clarification relation here naturally corresponds to translation and definability. If one can't formally move back and forth between L1 and L2, obviously no finite set of clarifications will suffice - since the crucial clarification relation for any 2 formulas may not exist! We can likewise check other mathematical conditions for definability to see if they are satisified. The same holds if one doesn't believe that there exists a translation manual. Of course, there is probably a different answer from each major philosopher of language here.

How about type 1 relations? If there are an infinite number of different syntactical formulations for some formula, the answer may be yes, unless we find a clarification relation that is able to pick out exactly one f2 out of such a set. It isn't quite clear what a language with an infinite number of syntactical transitions would look like though. I'm guessing that we can't use a finite state machine to model such a language, but I haven't worked that out. The general idea is that a language with finite formulas that are completely syntactically ambiguous probably have no real use to us- since indeed, it seems that they cannot be clarified. So it would be akin to a word that has no *meaning*.

Answer (score 0):

Person A's mind emitted the claim, and person A's mind is not infinitely complex. If person B understood person A's mind perfectly - or at least, sufficiently - then person A's motivations for emitting the claim would be clear, and person B would have no further need for clarification. Because person A's mind is not infinitely complex, a finite number of questions would be sufficient, in theory, to reveal the inner structure of person A's mind at the necessary level of detail.

Comment: What if you are trying to convey 'the Tao'? "The Tao that can be told is not the eternal Tao". Or the Zen Flower Sermon, direct transmission of a teaching mind-to-mind, without words or letters?